# Restricting mouse dragging to a certain area in Map-box-gl-js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

Hey guys so I am displaying a map and I want to limit the user mouse dragging to a specific area. For example I want to limit user within New York city. The user can use mouse dragging within the area that covers the city but if the user wants move to see Las Vegas the user should be trapped within the limits of New York.

My map component is currently looking like this.

```
<Map
        mapboxAccessToken={TOKEN}
        // onResize=""
        initialViewState={{
          longitude: -73.935242,
          latitude: 40.730610,
          zoom: 8,
        }}
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          height: "100%",
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
        minZoom={8}
        // dragPan={false}
      >

        <FullscreenControl position="top-right" />
        <NavigationControl position="top-right" />

<Map/>
```

When I disable dragPan it disables all mouse dragging but I just want to disable mouse dragging if the user tries to gets out of New York boundaries.